# Django error rendering view caused by missing url args

Tags: django

I'm trying to render view after POST request. For some reason I cannot pass url parameters. This is interesting part of my view:

```
class PageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'my_template.html'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        formset = MyFormset(request.POST)
        form = MyForm(data=request.POST)
        if formset.is_valid() and form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form, formset)
        return render(request, self.template_name, context={'form': form, 'formset':formset})
```

And my url template is:

```
path('<int:type>/<slug:name>/', PageView.as_view(), name='page_view')
```

Error I am getting is following:

```
Reverse for 'page_view' with arguments '('', '')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<type>[0-9]+)/(?P<name>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$']
```

Comment: It means you have a `success_url`, a `{% url ... %}`, etc. that refers to the `page_view`, but where the parameters do not exist.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thanks! You are right, I've completely missed that.